How to format a large amount of text to look as if they are text messages
I have downloaded my girlfriend and my conversations on messenger for our entire relationship and want to make something for her. We met through these texts. Moved in together, etc.
What I want, is a way to format (either with a table or just text) the texts back and forth to look similar if not exact to what the phone view would look like. With our messages on either side of one another.
Part of the problems I have been running into are:

Just getting them separated properly
Keeping the message, our name, and the date together like messages do
When converting text to table I cant get the same ^  it makes each line a separate cell
It's a large amount of text so simpler things like drawing my own cells or spacing it myself would take a very long time

So far I havew separated the text through trial and error with applying heading styles and paragraph spacing options but this is how it looks right now.
Michael
Don't be sorry lol I would actually really enjoy that  and yah pretty much lol I work and I go out to have a good time with friends. I haven't really been looking for anybody until recently
Feb 01, 2022 6:11:58pm
Ashley
lol. I'm sorry
Feb 01, 2022 6:08:04pm
Ashley
Why single for so long? Working too much?Idk if I have ever asked anyone out before I think I might be bad at it
Feb 01, 2022 6:06:46pm
Ashley
Wanna go eat some food at the same place at the same time again sometime in the future
Feb 01, 2022 6:06:00pm
Ashley
Cool. Um.
Feb 01, 2022 6:05:41pm
Michael
Lmao they've been smoking longer than we've been alive. Yes as a mater of fact I am single, I have been for quite a while now.
Feb 01, 2022 6:05:05pm
Ashley
Smooth Ashley. Real smooth. Lol does not a charmer make. I smoked an unhealthy amount in mom and Tom's backseat. Idk how these two smoke as much as they do.
Feb 01, 2022 6:01:19pm
Ashley
So..I take it from ur profile thing.. ur single?
Feb 01, 2022 6:00:15pm
Okay as you can see, I also need to consolidate all the messages by the same person around the same time like this:
Ashley
message 1
message 2
message 3
Last message before response date and time
Michaelresponse
message 1
message 2
last message before response date and time
Etc...
And then all of the text messages are in reverse order. I would like to bew able to reverse sort them to where the oldest date comes first.
I know, its alot. PLEASE HELP

Maybe look into how much formatting you can apply using the Paragraph in Word.

Have you tried asking an AI? (I haven't, but it's the sort of thing you might hope an AI could do).

Possibly relevant: How to wrap every paragraph with a custom text box in Word? – though it looks as though you want to keep the date/time info visible, so you'd have to tinker with the proposed solution a bit.

Disclaimer: This is done via MS Word on Windows not Mac. However, you should most likely have equivalent commands, shapes on Mac.

You could use shapes instead of tables. Go to Insert -> Shapes, then select a shape from the Callouts section.



Change the shapes' colors, insert the text, and change the text alignment and colors.

Align the shapes on the right side for your messages and on the left side for the other person.

In between the messages, you can insert dates and times on the page.


You'll get something like this:


how did you do this?

this is perfect! is it a style?

@AshleyDeSherlia I edited my answer and added steps.

A long-term learning solution is to learn how to use your own 'Styles' in Word. This skill will make your life easier in any future document.
Create three styles, one for the participant name, one for the actual message, and one for the date and time. I would set these up as paragraph styles, but character styles may work for you if you combine any of the elements into a single paragraph.
You can even use justification or tab stops in each style to get a specific layout. In this case, you may need three styles for each participant in the conversation - luckily there is only two! When using this approach you can also set the background colour and any borders for each paragraph.
Using styles in this way will allow you to experiment easily with different typefaces and bolding. In the text part, a mono-spaced font may be more effective; the participant name could be a bold font, perhaps even 'All Caps/Small Caps' and the date/time some smaller non-bold system-looking font.

I have done so already but part of what I would like to do is make each message into its own box like on messenger

In the Style, under paragraph untick the box that says keep similar paragraphs together. I haven't had a pay with that for a long time, so your mileage may vary.
